# Restify public dir and rest dir

Tags: node.js, restify

how I can split my node.js app with an public dir, where all html files an an rest dir, where all rest services. I would like to have the following case. If the user oben the ip address he would see the html site of app. If the user needs some data the call ipaddress/api/xyz and get the json data from rest api.

With my code, if I look at the ipaddress I see the html file, but have no access to rest api.

```
var restify = require('restify');
var carServices = require('./CarServices.js')


var ip_address = '127.0.0.1';
var port = '8080';

var server = restify.createServer({
  name: 'myapp'
});


server.use(restify.queryParser());
server.use(restify.bodyParser());
server.use(restify.CORS());




var PATH = '/api/cars';
server.get({path : PATH, version: '0.0.1'}, carServices.findAllCars);
server.get({path: PATH + '/:carId', version: '0.0.1'}, carServices.findCar)


server.get(/.*/,restify.serveStatic({
    directory: './public',
    default: 'index.html'
 }));

server.listen(port, ip_address, function(){
    console.log('%s listen at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

Comment: Your code seems fine. Are you saying that 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/cars' does not invoke carServices.findAllCars()? Perhaps there are bugs in your handlers? Please provide more details on what "no access to rest api" means.

Comment: Ohh Thanks. I post the projekt on github https://github.com/aBuder/NodeRestify

I would like to have the following case. If the user serve the domain, he would see the index.html file. If I server the domain/api/cars I would like to see the data as json.

Answer (score 0):

Your server.get() calls should specify the path (not an object) as the first argument:

```
server.get(PATH, carServices.findAllCars);
server.get(PATH + '/:carId', carServices.findCar)
```